# How to implement correctly one getter from auth.js into users.js file getter? (Vue.js)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am trying to filter out my user by using getters in 2 different files. How can these both be used together correctly?

**users.js**

```
 getAllUsersById(state) {
      return state.userIds.map(id => state.UserById[id])   
    }
```

**auth.js**

```
getAuthUser(state) {
      return state.user
    },
```

So getAuthUser from auth.js should be implemented inside users.js and get filtered out from getAllUsers.

,

Comment: If I've understood right, `return state.userIds.map(id => state.userById[id]).filter(user => user.id != getAuthUser(state).id)` is what you need

Comment: Should I just import getAuthUser from auth.js and that's all?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Just like in vanilla js

Comment: wait... In the post is not clear: those getters are Vuex getters?

Answer (score 0):

To access Vuex getters from another getter you have to pass `store.getters` to it:

**auth.js**

```js
[...]

getters: {
  getAuthUser: state => state.user
}

[...]
```

**users.js**

```js
[...]

getters: {
  getAllUsersById: (state, getters) => state.userIds.map(id => state.userById[id]).filter(user => user.id != getters.getAuthUser.id)
}

[...]
```

Since all vuex modules should be menaged by the same Vuex store no import is needed: providing `(state, getters)` as an argument of `getAllUsersById` gives the method access to all the getters inside Vuex in addition of the state.

Comment: Can you please explain this part?
To access Vuex getters from another getter you have to pass store.getters to it:

Comment: All vuex modules should be menaged by the same vuex store, so no import is needed: providing `(state, getters)` as an argument of `getAllUsersById` gives the method access whole getters inside vuex in addition of the state... I'll update the answare

Comment: id is not defined